# Continuous distribution: Let $U ∼ Uniform[0, 1]$. Compute each of the following.

Tags: probability

Let $U ∼ Uniform[0, 1]$. Compute each of the following.

$(a) P(U ≤ 0)$

$(b) P(U = 1/2)$

$(c) P(U < −1/3)$

$(d) P(U ≤ 2/3)$

$(e) P(U < 2/3)$

$(f) P(U < 1)$

$(g) P(U ≤ 17)$

Solution:

(a) 0 (b) 0 (c) 0 (d) 2/3 (f) 1 (g) 1

How are they getting these numbers?

Comment: Have you been given a definition of uniform random variable?

Comment: Definition 2.4.1 A random variable X is continuous if
$P(X = x) = 0 , (2.4.1)$
for all $x ∈ R$ Given this. Then it proceeded with an example of uniform distribution being $P(a \leq X \leq b) = b - a$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$U$ is uniformly distributed over the continuous interval $[0;1]$.   By definition we have: $$\mathsf P(U\leqslant x)=\begin{cases} 0 &:& x < 0\\ x &:& 0\leqslant x< 1\\ 1&:& 1\leqslant x\end{cases}$$

And of course, $\mathsf P(U\leqslant x)=\mathsf P(U<x)$ and $\mathsf P(U=x)=0$ for any $x$, because continuous distributions have zero probability mass at any single point .

Everything else is just application of the definition.

Comment: What what it be if it were [1,4] instead of [0,1]?

Comment: I recommend you read this free textbook on mathematical statistics and basics of probability. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/91cf/33d456e68648d4323a27afccaab05afda435.pdf

Comment: @basbas When $W\sim\mathcal {Unif}[a;b]$, then $\mathsf P(W\leqslant x) = \begin{cases}0&:& x< a\\ (x-a)/(b-a) &:& a\leqslant x< b\\ 1 &:& b\leqslant x\end{cases}$